# Is there any way or any extension that can make Control+Tab work normally?

Tags: tabs, controls

With most browsers Control+Tab switches to the last tab open.  But in Google Chrome they decided to ignore that and it takes you to the next tab open.  I've tried some extensions that didn't seem to even acknowledge the problem.  Most Chrome based browsers follow Google but CCleaner and Opera are two that allow for the conventional "last tab used" option.

Is there any way of making this work properly?
Can you imagine if Window's Alt+Tab worked this way???

I tried extensions and looked in Google Chrome Settings.  No luck.